# Add value of the check box to PHP result?

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP shopping cart which is very simple and it works as it should.

However what i want to do is to add two checkboxes in the shopping cart with two different values for shipping costs.

for example one has a value of 7 and one has a value of 12.

I have this PHP in my shopping cart:

```
$totalAll = $totalAll + ($item['qty']*$item['price']) + 'ship';
```

And i echo the `$totalAll` like this:

```
<?php echo $totalAll;?>
```

I have these two checkboxes too:

```
<label>UK Shipping</label>
<input name="ship" type="checkbox" value="7" />

    <label>International Shipping</label>
<input name="ship" type="checkbox" value="12" />
```

so I need the `$totalAll` + `'ship'` value but the way i did it doesn't really make sense!

could someone help me out with this please?

Thanks

Comment: `foreach($_POST['ship'] as $cost) { $ship += $cost }` or something like that.

Comment: why are you adding an string `'ship'` to a number!?

Comment: You might what to change the last `+` with `.` because I guess you want concatenation, not summing

Comment: @Philipp OP just don't knows how to get real value. So he / she shows it by index.

Comment: you can make ship an array `name="ship[]"`, but are you sure the shipping options can be combined ? or maybe you should use radioboxes insted

Comment: can you be more specific please? what is cost?

Comment: Actually the user would select only any one of the shipping option, right?

Comment: use radio instead of checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i would recommend radio buttons. It doesnt make sense to add both kinds of shipping costs.

Second, adding "ship" to a number wont help you. You need the following in your receiveform (in my case test.php):

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="radio" name="ship" value="7">
    <input type="radio" name="ship" value="12">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

test.php:

```
$ship = $_POST['ship'];
$total = $totalAll + $ship;
```

This will give you the full price.

Dont forget to validate input! In general, its not a good practice to rely on the HTML form for calculating prices.

Comment: Excellent... This is the way to do it. is there any way to update the `$total` on radio button click without pressing the `submit` button?

Comment: Not with PHP. If you just want to show the user how much the current fee for shipping is, you should use JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<label>UK Shipping</label>
<input name="ship[]" type="checkbox" value="7" />

    <label>International Shipping</label>
<input name="ship[]" type="checkbox" value="12" />
```

PHP

```
   $ship = 0;
   foreach($_POST['ship'] as $s)
   {
      $ship += $s;
   }
   $totalAll += ($item['qty']*$item['price']) + $ship;
```

Comment: seems a little bit unsecure.. someone could manipulate the request and make 'ship' `-100` or something else..i

Comment: yes, you would have to compare those in your code for sure.. I just wanted to show how to access the values!

Answer (score 0):

You can use radio instead of checkbox:

```
<label for="uk">UK Shipping</label>
<input id="uk" name="ship" type="radio" value="7" />

<label for="international">International Shipping</label>
<input id="international" name="ship" type="radio" value="12" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use radio buttons instead of check boxes and store the shipping values on the server. This results in something like this:

```
$shipping = array(
    1 => 7,
    2 => 12
);

// nothing selected?
if (!isset($_REQUEST['ship'])) {
    die("error"); // your error handling..
}
$ship = $shipping[(int) $_REQUEST['ship']];
```

and the html

```
<label>UK Shipping</label>
<input name="ship" type="radio" value="1" />

<label>International Shipping</label>
<input name="ship" type="radio" value="2" />
```